# freebsd bcrypt install error

Tags: freebsd, port

/usr/ports/security/bcrypt

when I'm trying to install it I get this:

```
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c main.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c blowfish.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c rwfile.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c keys.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c wrapbf.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c endian.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -c wrapzl.c
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -o bcrypt main.o blowfish.o rwfile.o keys.o wrapbf.o endian.o wrapzl.o
wrapzl.o(.text+0x55): In function `douncompress':
: undefined reference to `uncompress'
wrapzl.o(.text+0x149): In function `docompress':
: undefined reference to `compress'
*** Error code 1
1 error
*** Error code 1
```

In makefile there is:

```
LDFLAGS+=       -lz
```

How to trace this error and solve problem?

**Edit:**
@arved, that is Makefile:

```
DEFAULTS = Makefile includes.h blowfish.h functions.h config.h
CC?= gcc
CFLAGS?= -O2 -Wall
COMPILE = ${CC} ${CFLAGS}
OBJS = main.o blowfish.o rwfile.o keys.o wrapbf.o endian.o wrapzl.o
LDFLAGS?= -L/usr/local/lib -lz
PREFIX?= /usr/local
```

Comment: Side note: You may want to use OpenSSL's `bf` encryption instead of `bcrypt` as it's a much more widely supported format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

Can you post /usr/ports/security/bcrypt/work/bcrypt-1.1/Makefile ?

There should be a line like:
 LDFLAGS?= -L/usr/local/lib -lz
in it.

If you don't have it, it is a hint that your "sed" might be broken.

Comment: Makefile seems ok (see edit), anyway I used pkg_add and that did it.

Comment: if someone wants to debug this further, next step would be to test if your libz has the required functions, or to add more debug output by running "make -dl"